# SQL - Insert into a column depending on the value of another

Tags: sql

I'm using phpmyadmin and I want if a value in one column is between 1 and 10, then put a 1 in another column, and if it's between 11 and 20 then put a 2...and so on.

Comment: What RDBMS and table definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update your_table
set another_column = case when some_column between 1 and 10
                          then 1
                          when some_column between 11 and 20
                          then 2
                     end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE table
SET column1 = CEIL(column2/10);
```

Comment: if DBMS performs integer division then cast the column2 to float or decimal value